# How do I expand this CSS list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I've gotten my menu to expand by one level, but cannot figure out how to get it to expand a second time. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Root</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Link3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Lin4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Link3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #53BF58;
    width: 10em;
}

li ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #86EF8A;
}

li.active ul {
    display: block;
}

li ul li ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #86EF8A;
}

li ul li.active ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function hideAll() {
    var navList = document.getElementById("nav");
    for (var i=0; i<navList.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = navList.childNodes[i];
        if (node.tagName == "LI") {
            node.className = node.className.replace(new RegExp("\s?active", "i"), "");
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    var navList = document.getElementById("nav");
    for (var i=0; i<navList.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = navList.childNodes[i];
        if (node.tagName == "LI") {
            node.onclick = function() {
                hideAll();
                this.className += " active";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, I honestly think a library like jQuery will make your life easier in this case.

Comment: I agree with @pimvdb, jQuery makes your life SO much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`childNodes` only contains the direct children of the element--you need to recurse the `childNodes` of each node as well.

I highly recommend that you use a framework like jQuery (http://jquery.com) to make the code simpler:
http://jsfiddle.net/jDEhU/5/

```
$('#nav').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    var self = $(e.target), //get a reference to the clicked element
        active = self.parents().andSelf() //select all li's that should be active
            .addClass('active'); //and activate them
    $('#nav .active').not(active).removeClass('active'); //deactivate others  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Andy. However, I don't know jQuery and have very little time spare to learn it. Your code doesn't work and I'm unsure how to edit it to my needs. Is there a quick fix?

Comment: I've updated my jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/andyedinborough/jDEhU/9/, with the CSS in your original question with some minor modifications.  It appears to work as expected.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot! It works perfectly in your jsFiddle, however, when I try to put it onto my website it fails to work! I put your code inside 'menu.js' and then loaded it into my page straight after i loaded jquery. All the HTML / CSS is identical. What am I doing wrong? 

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="menu.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Well, with the script in `<head/>`, the `#nav` element doesn't exist at the time that the script executes.  Best practice is now to put your scripts at the end of the document, before `</body>`.  Alternatively, you could wrap the JavaScript code above in `$(function(){ /*put ondomready code here*/ });`, and jQuery will execute it when DOM is ready (all page elements are available for manipulation).

Comment: fantastic. Thanks a lot for the code / pointers. much appreciated. I think I'm going to have to find the time to learn jQuery :p

Comment: one more thing. the links in the menu won't work. I have a php switch setup on my template to include the correct content determined by the ?page=. All the other pages load fine, but anything in the the extending menu won't. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the line `e.preventDefault();` from the menu code.  This prevents the default action of clicking the link from happening--navigating to the requested page.  Also, instead of `href="#"`, use `href="javascript:;"` -- the first will cause the page scroll to the top, the second is what you really indend: do nothing.

Comment: Next: learn jQuery!  :]  It rocks, and will save you many headaches.  Ironically, it will also advance your knowledge of JavaScript substantially.  I thought I knew JavaScript, and then when I learned jQuery I realized I didn't know JavaScript hardly at all.

Comment: good to know. ill get on it. Before we part ways, fancy telling me how I'd keep the final <li>'s open when the user has clicked them? :)

Comment: If you're talking about how they all close when you click on something else, that is implemented with the last 3 lines, `$(document).click(...);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're only looping through the first level of nodes in your list. You need to go through the child elements of each subsequent list and add an onClick function to keep it expanding.